# Adding scroolbar to JList(including DefaultListModel object )

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I am trying to add a scrollbar to my `JList` and I have searched in this site there are a lot of thing about this topic but when ı try something from the referenced questions , any of them has worked.My code is here.

```
  list = new JList();
  list.setVisibleRowCount(1000);

  model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
  list.setModel(model);
  JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
  scrollpane.setViewportView(list);
```

How can I add scrollbar to the `JList`?  Anybody can help me for this question?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: I cannot add scroolbar

Comment: Where can't you add scrollbar? Where are you adding scrollbar?

Comment: Thanks for your attention.I have editted above.

Answer (score 3):

> How can ı add scroolbar to the JList?anybody can help me for this question?

The scrollbar will appear automatically when the number of elements in the list is greater than the size of the scroll pane.

I'm guessing that the `setVisibleRowCount(...)` method does nothing because you didn't add any data to the ListModel. Since there is nothing to render the size would be 0. Also using a row count of 1000 makes no sense since you can't display 1000 of lines of data on a single page. That property is meant to be a reasonable value like 10 so you can see 10 items of data at one time even when you have 100 items in the list.

Post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem (once you actually add data to the model and make the row count reasonable) if you need more help.